# How to fix parent element size after image scaling?

Tags: html, css, image, transform, scale

Good morning,
I am trying to scale my pictures to smaller sizes on website, but they are occupying the same space as original picture.

```
div {position: absolute; background: green; width: auto; height: auto;}
img {-moz-transform:scale(0.5); -webkit-transform:scale(0.5); transform: scale(0.5); transform-origin: 0 0; }
```

```
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Black_hole_-_Messier_87_%28cropped%29.jpg/1200px-Black_hole_-_Messier_87_%28cropped%29.jpg" alt="Black hole - Messier 87 (cropped).jpg">
</div>
```

There you can see it:
https://jsfiddle.net/m6h42zba/

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can just use width and height.

Comment: That's what **scale** does...it's an entirely visual effect. it does NOT affect *actual* sizing or layout.

Comment: so which command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
span {display: inline-block;}
img {width: 75%;}
```

HTML:

```
<span>
    <img src="example.png"/>
</span>
```

Simple solution